# Error al importar una variable de otro archivo en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

quise importar la variable de un archivo js con el siguiente codigo

```
const k = 13
export {k}
```

y el otro codigo js es el siguiente

```
import { k } from 'a.js'
window.onload = ()=>{
     document.write(k);
}
```

el codigo html es

```
    <script type="module" src="l.js"></script>
```

saltan dos errores el primero es

```
l.html:1 Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/pruebas/l.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

y el segundo es

```
l.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

he probado a cambiar nombres de los archivos y limpiar mi historial pero nada a funcionado alguna idea de que puede fallar

Comment: Haz que la URI sea una URL relativa al sitio. Así, no va a cargar `file://` sino `http://`. Como ves en el error, a menos que sea una URL que se resuelva por uno de esos protocolos como origen, no te deja usarlo (por seguridad)

Comment: @Alfabravo y eso como se hace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de lo que estés intentando. Estás usando algún servidor HTTP para ver esto (como Apache HTTP, nginx)? Si es así, pues le llegas a los archivos a través de `<script type="module" src="http://localhost//ruta/a/l.js"></script>` o lo que sea dependiendo de cómo configures tu servidor HTTP.

Si estás escribiendo sólo los archivos JS en tu computador y los abres en el navegador sin más, te toca es iniciarlo sin que valide CORS y diciéndole dónde está tu perfil con tus favoritos, cache y todo eso:

`chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=c:\my-chrome-data\data`

Comment: y eso donde hay que ponerlo

Comment: @patata depende de cuál es tu caso. CUál es tu caso? Qué es lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: Mi caso es el segundo no estoy usando ningún servidor